# using java lambda function operator (->) in thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am getting Exception evaluating `SpringEL` expression when using java lambda operator.

example: `list.stream().map(a -> a.toString()).reduce("",(a,b) -> a+b)`

Comment: why didn't you evaluate the result of this statement on Java side and pass it to the template engine?

Comment: I am populating table hence I need this operation for every iteration. But I can add this operation as static method and pass the list as argument. This approach wont give maintainable code.

Comment: You can't.Take a look the reference to know what you can do: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Comment: yeah it is not possible. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function similar to the following:

```
package com.mypackage;
public class CollectorsMap {
    public static final List<String> name(Stream<AbstractName> stream) {
        return stream.map(v->v.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

invoke it with something similar to the following (values is a list of values):

```
th:with="valueNames=${T(com.mypackage.CollectorsMap).name(values.stream())}"
```

This would return the list of name fields of the original list of objects.